# Keep @OrderColumn information of @ManyToMany when using JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Given the following entity

```
public class TempEntity {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable( /*someprops*/)
    @OrderColumn(name = "pos")
    private List<FooEntity> foos = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

How can I apply the ordering of the child entities of `TempEntity` when using the `CriteriaBuilder` to fetch childs of a `TempEntity`. Using the default `findAll()` of the JPA Repository keeps the order regarding the order column automatically.

As the column is only available in the `ManyToMany` joining table I can not find any way to access it to keep the order when fetching the `foos` from the `TempEntity`

Answer (score 0):

Use a JPQL/HQL query: `select f from TempEntity e join e.foos f order by index(f)`

Answer (score 0):

When joining with a list in Criteria API, you get a `ListJoin`, which has an `index()` method to get an expression for the index in the list:

```java
Root<TempEntity> fromTempEntity = query.from(TempEntity.class);
ListJoin<TempEntity, FooEntity> fooJoin = fromTempEntity.join(TempEntity_.foos);

query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(fooJoin.index())
     . ...
```